# C# Get Computer's MAC address "OFFLINE"

Tags: c#, mac-address

Is there any way to get computer's mac address when there is no internet connection in c#?
I'am able to get when I have connection but not able to get when I am offline. But strongly I need the mac address for my work.

My online code;

```
var macAddr =
      (from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
       where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
       select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: can you just remove the `where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up` line?

Comment: When online, mac address; 4CEB428D5072 When offline, mac address 4CEB428D5073. Why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From WMI:

```
public static string GetMACAddress1()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMOS.Get();
    string macAddress = String.Empty;
    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
        object tempMacAddrObj = objMO["MacAddress"];

        if (tempMacAddrObj == null) //Skip objects without a MACAddress
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (macAddress == String.Empty) // only return MAC Address from first card that has a MAC Address
        {
            macAddress = tempMacAddrObj.ToString();              
        }
        objMO.Dispose();
    }
    macAddress = macAddress.Replace(":", "");
    return macAddress;
}
```

From System.Net namespace:

```
public static string GetMACAddress2()
{
    NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    String sMacAddress = string.Empty;
    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
    {
        if (sMacAddress == String.Empty)// only return MAC Address from first card  
        {
            //IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties(); Line is not required
            sMacAddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
        }
    } return sMacAddress;
}
```

Slightly modified from [How to get the MAC address of system - C-Sharp Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ahsanm.m/how-to-get-the-mac-address-of-system-using-Asp-NetC-Sharp/)

Comment: Is the line `IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();` needed?

Comment: @Joel No this line is not required based testing I just ran on my dev box. Updated answer to reflect my testing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use WMI in C# (`System.Management`) to get a list of `Win32_NetworkAdapter`'s which contains a `MACAddress` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why it is showing different mac address when our network is disconnected? any idea?

Comment: 0C1320524153 mac address is showing when our network is disconnected.

Comment: If it's a wireless network adapter then it'll show a different MAC address for each different wireless network that it's connected to.