# C#: MAC addres reading

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version

Following script to read MAC address in C# and working fine for .Net Framework 4

```
macAddr =
    (
        from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
        select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()

    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

But the problem is I need to build it for .Net Framework 3

When I use .Net Framework 3 then following error occurs

**Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface[]'.  'Where' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

(are you missing an assembly reference?)**

What will be the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: `Are you missing a reference or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?`

Comment: I tried to add reference System.Linq but it is not available in Assemblies

Comment: This link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783954/c-sharp-get-computers-mac-address-offline

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in .net version 3.0 you cannot use Linq query as above. Use a simple foreach loop as shown below to iterate through the list and fetch the value.

```
foreach(var nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
   if(nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
   {
    return nic.GetPhysicalAddress();
   }
}
return string.Empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature `System.Linq` was introduced in the .NET Framework 3.5.
Please refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.90).aspx

If you are using .NET 3.5 then add the update the references.